# Membership signup/renewal erroneously reports missing fields after upgrade to 4.7.3

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, custom-fields

Recently upraded to CiviCRM 4.7.3 on this site: http://oaem.ca/

After the upgrade, the membership signup and renewal process is broken in the following way.

The signup/renewal form at https://oaem.ca/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1 now includes an additional "Organization Details" form, which is not set in any profile, and which is not wanted. It appears to conflict with the membership data that I want to collect, and which is collected using a custom contribution profile.

Filling in both forms appears to work at first, but when the user reaches the confirmation page, they see this report:

```
Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:
Organization Name is a required field.
Phone (Main) is a required field.
Email (Main) is a required field.
Street Address is a required field.
City is a required field.
Postal Code is a required field.
Country is a required field.
State/Province is a required field.
```

So the additional data on the 1st screen does not get passed to the final screen.

This persists even if I switch off the the custom profile form in an attempt to use the 'default' form which is being added.

[This is what the screen used to look like (compare with current page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdpAm.png)

Any suggestions as to what is wrong and how to fix it very gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may all be stuff you already know.

If you have a look on the Title and Settings for that page eg

civicrm/admin/contribute/settings?reset=1&action=update&id=1

you should see that you have 'allow individuals to contribute 'on behalf of' an organisation' ticked. And below that it should specify the Organisation profile in use. You can either Edit it via that page, or go direct to Profiles.

NOTE: at civicrm/admin/uf/group?reset=1 it may be on the Reserved Profiles tab, which might be why you aren't seeing it.

on the page at https://oaem.ca/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1 I do not see the 'on behalf of' checkbox which I do see on your old screenshot - is that because you have now made it required?

Comment: Thanks. This has *half* fixed my problem. The radio buttons "Optional Required - Check 'Required' to force ALL users to contribute/signup on behalf of an organization" was unset, but appeared to have defaulted to 'required' when in an unset state. I'm guessing that is a new setting in the new version. Setting to 'optional' means that is now possible to complete a signup *if* the user chooses 'signup on behalf of an organisation'. However if signing up as individual it fails with original warnings, although user cannot add that information.

Comment: In other words, the organisation address fields are treated as required, even when the user is not joining on behalf of an organisation. I could just make those fields optional, but they *should* be required when the user is signing up for an org.

Comment: may sound a pain, but do you want to quickly whip up a new page and see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: Not only did a replacement work, but when I put the 'required' settings back on the original one, that one now works too. Go figure. Thanks for your help.